# giving rotation to a View disappears some of its content

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, rotation, transition

I have 10 views in my screen with this style:

```
<View style={{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#005b96',
}}>
   <Text style={{
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: '600',
      color: '#eee',
   }}>{number}</Text>
</View>
```

And this is what I get [image]
But as I add `transform:[{rotate: '5deg'}]` to the `View`'s style, all the numbers other than 1 disappear! [image]
it seems rotation shrinks the room for its content so texts get disappeared, but since 1 is lean enough, remains as before!
I tried giving extra width and height to `Text` but it didn't work!

Comment: rotation should not shrink the content

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is just my assumption! don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this style to the `Text`'s style did the trick!

```
width: '100%',
textAlign: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'black', // gave the background so the effect will be obvious.
```

and got this:
[image]